# how to pass the date object from the date picker to method

Tags: angular

as shown below i have a date picker element and once the user tries to change the data the method  `onDateChanged()` wil be called.
i would like to know how to pass the date object from the date picker to this method.

**html**

```
                <div id=idDateOfPesticide1Dose class="date">
                    <input  type="date" id="start" [(ngModel)]="iDatePasser.date" (ngModelChange)="onDateChanged()" name="trip-start"
                        value="2021-07-21"
                        min="2021-01-01" max="2090-12-31">
                </div>
```

**code**:

```
export interface IDatePasser {
  date: string
}
export class PesticidesTypesAndDosesComponent implements OnInit {
iDatePasser:IDatePasser;
....
....

constructor() { 
this.iDatePasser ={} as IDatePasser;

  private onDateChanged():void { //how to pass the date object from the date picker to this method
    console.log("data changed")
    
  }
```

Comment: Maybe like this ? `(ngModelChange)="onDateChanged($event)"` and in your ts `onDateChanged(event: any) :void { console.log(event); }`. But your function must be public

Comment: @Emilien would you please tell me how to obtain the month? i used event.getMonth() but i receive getMonth is not a function

Comment: You have to determine the type of `$event`. I'll do it this after-noon an dtry to let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use Angular's double binding the value should be already applied in
`this.iDatePasser.date` via `[(ngModel)]="iDatePasser.date"`.

Another approach is to use the `onDateChanged` together with the `$event` e.g.:

`<input [ngModel]="iDatePasser.date" (ngModelChange)="onDateChanged($event)">`

with on `onDateChanged` like this:

```js
  public onDateChanged(event: any) {
    console.log(new Date(event).getMonth());    
  }
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zaggi-angular-input-type-date-9533np?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is a simple Stackblitz too.

Comment: would you please tell me how to obtain the month? i used event.getMonth() but i receive getMonth is not a function

Comment: You can create a new `Date` object with the given `event` string e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth